# mergeMaps doesn't work when first map has no elements?

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, hashmap

I try to merge two maps

```
      private void mergeMaps(HashMap<String, FailureExample> current,
                           HashMap<String, FailureExample> other) {

        current.forEach((k, v) -> other.merge(k, v,
                (v1, v2) -> {
                    FailureExample answer = new FailureExample();

                    addFromListWithSizeLimit(v1, answer);
                    addFromListWithSizeLimit(v2, answer);

//                    answer.requests.addAll(v1.requests);
//                    answer.requests.addAll(v2.requests);
                    return answer;
                }));
    }
```

but when current has 0 elements, the lambda is not executed.

Isn't merge should do union in case no merge is possible?

I want:

```
map1{} ; map2{<a,<a1>>} returns map3{<a,<a1>>}

map1{<a,<b1>>} ; map2{<a,<a1>>} returns map3{<a,<a1, b1>>}
```

Comment: Forget that you are trying to merge maps for a second, and imagine you call `forEach` on an empty list: how many times would the lambda be executed?

Comment: Besides the fact that you are modifying the `other` map, in other words, `map2` and `map3` are identical, the code exactly does what you describe. It’s not clear why you expect something different and what for. When both maps have disjunct keys, the lambda expression won’t get executed either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `forEach` on an empty collection, there is obviously nothing on which to execute the lambda.

If `HashMap.merge` is the way you want to merge the lists, you could swap the maps round in the case that the first is empty:

```
if (current.isEmpty()) {
  HashMap<String, FailureExample> tmp = current;
  current = other;
  other = tmp;
}
```

However, that will add elements to `other`, rather than `current`.

Alternatively, you can just `putAll` everything into the first map:

```
if (current.isEmpty()) {
  current.putAll(other);
}
```

Comment: but then again it won't add items which are not in the for-each. Meaning items in the `"other"` map.